# How to use signal protocol to encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: python, cryptography, signal-protocol

I was reverse engineering WhatsApp web. I created a custom client in python to connect to WhatsApp with websocket, generate a QR code, and save the login credentials to a file. When I tried to use it, I realized that WhatsApp's end to end encryption is real. I used [this](https://pypi.org/project/signal-protocol/) python module to generate 2 signal protocol keys: `pre_key_pair = curve.KeyPair.generate()`, the I sent the public key to WhatsApp on my phone with the generated QR code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import websockets as WSocket
import asyncio, json, requests
import base64, random
import qrcode
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import *
import signal_protocol

wsurl = "wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws"

async def whatsapp(uri):
    async with WSocket.connect(uri, extra_headers={"Origin": "https://web.whatsapp.com"}) as ws:
        keys = signal_protocol.curve.KeyPair.generate()

        pubkey = base64.b64encode(keys.public_key().serialize()[1:]).decode()
                                                            #   ^ I removed the first byte, bc it is every time \x05
                                                            #   (it is the key type)
        browserid = "8TDLL9cktZvZvMiicMrubw=="
        
        await ws.send('1633259071.--1,["admin","init",[2,2138,13],["Python","-","x86_64"],"{}",true]'.format(browserid))
        data = await ws.recv()
        print(data)
        lst = data.split(',')
        idk = lst[0]
        del lst[0]
        parsed = json.loads(','.join(lst))
        auth = parsed["ref"]
        
        qrtext = '{},{},{}'.format(auth, pubkey, browserid)
        print(qrtext)
        #await ws.send('1633276651.--1,["admin","Conn","reref"]') #retry
        
        code = qrcode.make(qrtext) #.show()
        root = Tk()
        w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
        m = min(w, h) // 2
        root.resizable(False, False)
        root.geometry(f'{m}x{m}+{w//2-m//2}+{h//2-m//2}')
        buffer = BytesIO()
        code.resize((m, m)).save(buffer, format="png")
        buffer.seek(0)
        img = PhotoImage(data=buffer.read())
        lable = Button(root, image=img).place(x=0, y=0)
        root.attributes('-topmost', True)
        root.overrideredirect(True)
        root.update()
        
        res = await ws.recv()
        print(res)
        with open("token", "wt") as o:
            o.write(res)
            o.write('\n')
            o.write(browserid)
            o.write(',')
            o.write(base64.b64encode(keys.private_key().serialize()).decode())
            o.close()
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(whatsapp(wsurl))
```

My problem is, how can I decrypt the cyphertext that sents me back WhatsApp.
Here is my client:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import websockets as WSocket
import asyncio, json, requests
import base64, random, hmac, hashlib
import signal_protocol

wsurl = "wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws"

def parse(token):
    lines = token.strip().split('\n')
    chunks = lines[0].strip().split(',')
    del chunks[0]
    jdata = json.loads(','.join(chunks))
    print(jdata[0])
    plus = lines[1].strip().split(',')
    jdata[1]["browserID"] = plus[0]
    jdata[1]["key"] = signal_protocol.curve.PrivateKey.deserialize(base64.b64decode(plus[1]))
    return jdata[1]

def processdata(data):
    print(data)

async def whatsapp(uri, token):
    async with WSocket.connect(uri, extra_headers={"Origin": "https://web.whatsapp.com"}) as ws:
        print("Logging in...")
        await ws.send('1633521509.--0,["admin","init",[2,2138,13],["Python","-","x86_64"],"{}",true]'.format(token["browserID"]))
        print(await ws.recv())
        await ws.send('1633521518.--1,["admin","login","{}","{}","{}","takeover"]'.format(token["clientToken"],
                                                                                          token["serverToken"],
                                                                                          token["browserID"])
                      )
        data = await ws.recv()
        print(data)
        chunks = data.split(',')
        del chunks[0]
        jdata = json.loads(','.join(chunks))
        if type(jdata) == list and jdata[0] == "Cmd" and jdata[1]["type"] == "challenge":
            print("Solve challange...")
            await ws.send('1633521518.--1,["admin","login","{}","{}","{}","takeover"]'.format(token["clientToken"],
                                                                                              token["serverToken"],
                                                                                              token["browserID"])
                          )
            #print(jdata)
            resolve = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(token["key"].serialize(), base64.b64decode(jdata[1]["challenge"]), hashlib.sha256).digest())
            ready = '1633521544.--2,["admin","challenge","{}","{}","{}"]'.format(resolve.decode(), token["serverToken"], token["browserID"])
            print(ready)
            await ws.send(ready)
        elif type(jdata) == list and jdata[0] == "Conn" or jdata["status"] == 200:
            print("OK")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid token")
            
        processdata(data)
        
        # 1633415961.--2,["admin","challenge","nJOSG/8l6ee33hVSyqhWwGTlEnGDxiSXwGGK9+zAB+w=","1@LV3dAbOqdpPZPnitEw1xI67X7fBTFHUnINQ8ZUdzpmUPWm0pKkJIN/sgxRSog1jqIt+f3AfePp5k1A==","8TDLL9cktZvZvMiicMrubw=="]
        # 1633415954.--1,["admin","login","u5a7azVDJzsr7Vpmpkga4sf5LbSpRW7jqdx6/j9GBGs=","1@LV3dAbOqdpPZPnitEw1xI67X7fBTFHUnINQ8ZUdzpmUPWm0pKkJIN/sgxRSog1jqIt+f3AfePp5k1A==","8TDLL9cktZvZvMiicMrubw==","takeover"]
        while True:
            data = await ws.recv()
            processdata(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("token", "rt") as o:
        token = o.read()
        o.close()
    asyncio.run(whatsapp(wsurl, parse(token)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an open source project that does exactly that, but now unfortunately whatsapp forced an updated, that changed a lot, and no longer supports that.

Here is the project: [WhatsApp Web reverse engineered](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng)

**EDIT:**

So I was wrong with signal protocol, because whatsapp used curve25519.

When recived _login ([source](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py#L162)) generate the private key, and get the publi key from the privet key:

```
self.loginInfo["privateKey"] = curve25519.Private();
self.loginInfo["publicKey"] = self.loginInfo["privateKey"].get_public();
```

When recived Conn ([source](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py#L200)) get the "secret" from the recived json object, and generate the shared secret from the recived secret and your private key:

```
self.connInfo["secret"] = base64.b64decode(jsonObj[1]["secret"]);
self.connInfo["sharedSecret"] = self.loginInfo["privateKey"].get_shared_key(curve25519.Public(self.connInfo["secret"][:32]), lambda a: a);
sse = self.connInfo["sharedSecretExpanded"] = HKDF(self.connInfo["sharedSecret"], 80);
```

Where `HKDF` is ([source](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/e26f337005bf704368b67c95aef0c0d717fb6a31/backend/whatsapp.py#L44)):

```
def HmacSha256(key, sign):
    return hmac.new(key, sign, hashlib.sha256).digest();

def HKDF(key, length, appInfo=""):                      # implements RFC 5869, some parts from https://github.com/MirkoDziadzka/pyhkdf
    key = HmacSha256("\0"*32, key);
    keyStream = "";
    keyBlock = "";
    blockIndex = 1;
    while len(keyStream) < length:
        keyBlock = hmac.new(key, msg=keyBlock+appInfo+chr(blockIndex), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest();
        blockIndex += 1;
        keyStream += keyBlock;
    return keyStream[:length];
```

Then use this to get anther 2 keys ([source](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py#L207)):

```
keysEncrypted = sse[64:] + self.connInfo["secret"][64:];
keysDecrypted = AESDecrypt(sse[:32], keysEncrypted);
self.loginInfo["key"]["encKey"] = keysDecrypted[:32];
self.loginInfo["key"]["macKey"] = keysDecrypted[32:64];
```

Where `AESDecrypt` is ([source](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/e26f337005bf704368b67c95aef0c0d717fb6a31/backend/whatsapp.py#L77)):

```
def AESUnpad(s):
    return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])];

def AESDecrypt(key, ciphertext):                        # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20868265
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size];
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv);
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:]);
    return AESUnpad(plaintext);
```

When recived an encrypted message ([source](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py#L180)) use `self.loginInfo["key"]["encKey"]` to decrypt it:

```
decryptedMessage = AESDecrypt(self.loginInfo["key"]["encKey"], messageContent[32:]);
```

Comment: Now my 1y old question has got a proper answer from myself.